# npm install hangs when using Docker to install libraries

Tags: node.js, react-native, docker, docker-compose, expo

Here's the deal. I'm trying to setup my environment to develop a react native application using expo. Since I'm working on a Windows OS, I'd like to setup using Docker and docker-compose.

First I build my image, installing expo-cli from a node image. Then I use docker-compose to specify a volume and ports to expose.

Since at this point I have to project initialized, what I do is, use `docker-compose run` to initialize my project and then the same to install specific project libraries. But when I do, at some random point, the installation hangs.

Now it seems like it's docker related, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.18.3

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN npm install --no-save -g expo-cli
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN adduser user
USER user
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    expose:
      - "19000"
      - "19001"
      - "19002"
      - "19003"
    ports:
      - "19000:19000"
      - "19000:19001"
      - "19000:19002"
      - "19000:19003"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: sh -c "cd myapp && npm start"
```

Assuming my app is called myapp

Here are the commands I use to install additional npm packages and initialize project:

```
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "npx expo-cli init myapp"
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "cd /app/myapp && npm install react-navigation --verbose"
```

I see that several things happen, but it always hangs somewhere and never at the same place everytime I start from skratch.

Please help!

Comment: Why not [download and install Node directly on your host](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)?  There are prebuilt Windows binaries.  That avoids all of the indirection issues that Docker introduces here (for a React Native application, also the difficulties of running a GUI application in Docker).

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing right now but I feel like Docker is an easier practice to manage versions and quickly be up and running for anyone who would join me on developing the app. Plus its easier for testing into ci pipelines when everything is dockerized :/